# RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged does not call the onBindViewHolder to update the data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

On data change we are calling notifyDataSetChanged to update the recyclerview data to the latest. Some scenario is working properly, but In some scenario is not calling the onBindViewHolder to update the data. The notifyDataSetChanged is not calling the onBindViewHolder.

But the it's getting updated when changing the orientation or going to next screen and coming back to this screen.  And also in our case we are showing the overlay dialog(below to action bar) on some cases as per the requirement, thought of this may be an issue.

In case of any dialog was shown on top of this, is that recyclerview will update the data whenever new data available?

Any suggestions? Thanks.